# Which is faster? input[type="submit"] or [type="submit"]

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Which of the following CSS selectors is faster?

```
input[type="submit"] {
    /* styles */
}
```

or

```
[type="submit"] {
    /* styles */
}
```

Just Curious!

Comment: Apparently, former one is faster, as it filters away tags other than `<input>`.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I'd be happy to see your dupe. ;)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Yeah I sort of thought the same, but I'm not sure after reading [this article on CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) about "right to left" selector reading.

Comment: Why the unfriendly downvote? I'm just curious if we can further optimize some of our everyday selectors!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but most performance questions are often unanswerable because they're too microscopic in scale for anyone to make a reasonable judgement.

Comment: Just my two cents: even if the actual performance difference doesn’t matter, I was searching the syntax to do this thing and this came up... So not useless question :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the latter is faster, simply because it's less information to parse; however, I would think that with each instance, given the speed of servers and clients, you are talking a matter of nano-seconds at best.  I think there are a larger number of issues to be concerned about when it comes to processing speeds like redundant code, use of white space and the like.

Comment: Nice, yet another unjustified downvote.  The problem with my answer was??

Comment: I'll upvote to make up for whoever downvoted without a comment. ;) Still curious about performance though.

Comment: @Web_Designer Thanks, I appreciate it!  I really think that the performance issue is negligible at best.  Like I mentioned, with processing speeds these days, I don't think this difference will be noticeable.  Perhaps if you were running thousands of CSS code for your `inputs` you may notice a slight difference but even at that it would be slight.